# action extension for pdf

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, debugging, pdf

I am trying to just open pdf file in my app using extension, I am able to use the default one provided by Xcode for image to display image, even I am able to show pdf when activation rule is not set, but we cannot publish app without specifying what kind of extension we are using in our app.

I tried many methods but failed
I did little changes to info.plist based on some question on stackoverflow but Xcode is throwing error saying **unable to read property list**

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>
        SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
        ).@count == 1
        </string>
        </dict>
```

this is my actionviewcontroller code:

```
{


@IBOutlet weak var myPdfView: PDFView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get the item[s] we're handling from the extension context.

    // For example, look for an image and place it into an image view.
    // Replace this with something appropriate for the type[s] your extension supports.
    for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
        for provider in item.attachments! {
            if provider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePDF as String) {
                // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
                weak var weakPDFView = self.myPdfView
                provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypePDF as String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (imageURL, error) in
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                        if let strongPDFView = weakPDFView {
                            if let imageURL = imageURL as? URL {
                                strongPDFView.document = PDFDocument(data: try! Data(contentsOf: imageURL))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                break
            }
        }

    }
}

@IBAction func done() {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Xcode is throwing error saying unable to read property list

Typo. It is

```
</dict>
```

not

```
<dict/>
```

Comment: I am sorry for that, I have edited the question but after changing it in Xcode I am still getting same error